# Visudo NOPASSWD not working on specific file

Tags: command-line, scripts, sudo, password, visudo

I'm trying to exclude one script I wrote from asking the password when executed, even if it contains a "sudo" command

so i've edited sudoers through visudo adding

```
myuser  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/script.sh
```

but it stills asks for sudo password when i execute it,
i've tried to put a more broad rule like

```
myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

and it works, but it's not what i want, i would like only that command not to ask me for the password

this is my sudoers file

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
myuser  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/script.sh

# Members of the admin group may gain privileges root
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: Are you sure the script path is `/home/script.sh` - not `/home/<username>/script.sh`?

Comment: @gabriele-niola in addition to what @steeldriver have said, could you try after removing space between `NOPASSWD:` and `/home/script.sh`. I just checked my `sudoers` file and that's the first thing I've noticed. Thanks.

Comment: To both, i've tried removing the space with no successo
And I obtained the Path by dragging the file itself in the terminal, so It should be right